# Suppress -Wproperty-no-attribute not working in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, suppress-warnings

In an Xcode 5, ARC, iPhone project, I have received a large number of warnings reading "No 'assign', 'retain', or 'copy' attribute is specified - 'assign' is assumed." I know what this warning means, and why I might want to fix it. But this would take a long time given the size of my project, so I instead want to suppress the warning. However, setting the `-Wno-property-no-attribute` flag on all of my `.m` files didn't fix anything, nor did setting the flag at Custom Compiler Flags > Other Warning Flags. I also tried `#pragma GCC/clang diagnostic ignored "-Wproperty-no-attribute"` before my property declarations, and have cleaned my build folder many times. The warnings persist. (Also, the -w flag did not work to suppress all warnings, when applied to my `.m` files.)

What should I do?

Comment: Huh? Assign/retain/copy does not apply to ARC.

Comment: @AbhiBeckert is correct - that warning is for *non* ARC, using manual memory management. ARC does not assume ``assign``, it assumes ``strong``. Double check that ARC is actually enabled for your project.

Comment: And also double check ARC isn't disabled for the individual files in the project. You can enable ARC for a project but disable for specific files.

Comment: Really? Under "Objective-C Automatic Reference Counting" I have YES, and I have only one file in my project (not one of the ones generating warnings) with a compiler flag set (-fno-objc-arc). I only started getting this warning with a recent Xcode update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that I had made a small typo in the Custom Compiler Flags entry (although I still do not know why the file-per-file flags didn't work), and that the LLVM warning about this was almost invisible, being swamped in the hundreds of other warnings generated.

Answer (score 2):

The pragma statement should be this: `#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wobjc-property-no-attribute"`